# How to display an image or pdf after selection

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

if the user uploads an image file, it will display the image on the selection. But how about pdf? because in my project requirement when the user wants to upload a pdf file it will show a pdf image/logo. I need an assist for this type of issue.

Thank you so much in advance

here my html codes :

<img class="img-thumbnail thumbnail-size" src="#" width="50" height="50" id="image3"

```html
<li>
<img class="img-thumbnail thumbnail-size" src="#" width="50" height="50" id="image3" />
<button class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-sm" onclick="ClearImage('3')" type="button" />
<input id="file-3" name="uploadImages" type="file" onchange="readURL(this, '3');" class="filestyle" data-buttontext="DOCUMENT 2" data-buttonname="btn-primary" data-size="xs">
</li>
```

/>

Comment: i already can upload the pdf file but in selection display it show like crash image. so i just want to fix that crash image into pdf image

Comment: for img src can be define by one url only right? how about i want to define for 2 url. Because in my case, for any type of format picture can be display but for pdf it show crash image and not showing the pdf icon/logo

Comment: For creating the thumbnail, consider using an imaging toolkit like LEADTOOLS  that supports multiple image and document formats. The `RasterCodecs` class can load a PDF as an image in a `RasterImage` object that can be used to easily [generate a thumbnail](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/l/rasterimage-createthumbnail.html). (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)